# Retreive word, pdf from archived database in blob column

Tags: pdf, ms-word, base64, blob

We have ended our contract with a Saas tool. We have received our archived data as a Oracle database with word & pdf documents in a Blob column.  We were told that the Blob data is in Base64 binary and needs to be decoded before downloading to a file.  When looking at the data in the Blob column it looks like this:

```
       í]pÅ™þgµ«•,­´–‘°
8„I–
c#Y’-Ù²ül‡àF»#íˆÝõÎ®ŒHRˆ@!  qsG\¹‹I ¹ÜåçQ<ª #G.<'Áªâ«
÷È«øB‘J¼÷ýÝ3»#iW–d‡×Í/}ÛÓÓÝÿß÷ßwïÎãðç½ç›ÿƒ&ÐZ*£¹J*wS€
N$LÔmŸ;‘ËåøÔz çÑÛŠ~wß÷èüë*ýDÇêÍ÷,ßÐ@TCÃÃ÷ÔßS?ÑBˆ*ý
Ô|Ñã7I4ÔLÎã¦\®ö¤ÇÝ+>U?
```

The same as hexdump:

```
00000000 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ed 5d 0b 70 1c c5 |...........].p..|
00000010 99 fe 67 b5 ab 95 2c ad b4 96 91 b0 8d 0d 03 38 |..g...,........8|
00000020 84 18 49 96 0d 06 63 07 23 59 92 2d d9 b2 fc 90 |..I...c.#Y.-....|
00000030 6c 87 e0 03 46 bb 23 ed 88 dd 9d f5 ce ae 8c 48 |l...F.#........H|
00000040 52 88 40 02 21 09 71 12 73 47 5c b9 8b 49 20 b9 |R.@.!.q.sG\..I .|
00000050 dc e5 12 e7 51 3c aa 20 90 23 47 2e 3c 12 27 c1 |....Q<. .#G.<.'.|
```

Have tried Base64 library in PL/SQl, Java, Linux to decode but does not work.

Java:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(input_file);
```

PL/SQL:

```
utl_file.put(l_output, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(vblob));

utl_file.putl_output, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(vblob)));

raw_decoded := utl_encode.base64_decode(vblob);
utl_file.put_raw(l_output, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(raw_decoded));
```

Could you advise if this is a Base64 data or what format it is in?  The expected result is to render blob in MS Word, PDF documents.

Comment: No, this doesn't look like Base64 at all. Try `base64 somefile` on Linux to see a real example. Have you tried to identify the data with e.g. `file blob_example_file` on Linux?

Comment: Yes tried linux libraries (Base64 command) also.  Have worked on converting Base64 images to jpg in the past.  So kindof familiar with Base64 streams.  Posted to confirm that this is not Base64 and also to see if anyone know what format this is.  Thank you for your response & suggestion.

Comment: BTW: it might help to add a hexdump of the example. I'm pretty sure that copy & paste of the string you have there now will not be transparent. Options would be `od` (coreutils) or `hexdump` (util-linux) tools.

Comment: This looks like it could be Word's binary, proprietary file format - what you'd see if you opened a *.doc ( *not* docx) file in a text editor. If that is the case, theoretically writing the content to a text file then saving it with the extension `.doc` would work. But that's not certain, just something I'd try...

Comment: @Stefan hexdump is producing (first few lines)

00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 ed 5d 0b 70 1c c5  |...........].p..|
00000010  99 fe 67 b5 ab 95 2c ad  b4 96 91 b0 8d 0d 03 38  |..g...,........8|
00000020  84 18 49 96 0d 06 63 07  23 59 92 2d d9 b2 fc 90  |..I...c.#Y.-....|
00000030  6c 87 e0 03 46 bb 23 ed  88 dd 9d f5 ce ae 8c 48  |l...F.#........H|
00000040  52 88 40 02 21 09 71 12  73 47 5c b9 8b 49 20 b9  |R.@.!.q.sG\..I .|
00000050  dc e5 12 e7 51 3c aa 20  90 23 47 2e 3c 12 27 c1  |....Q<. .#G.<.'.|

Comment: @Cindy
We thought so too and tried opening in directly in Word as suggested. But
Word is not reconizing the format and keeps asking for format it is in. Tried
selecting 'Windows default', 'MS-DOS' but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.  Turns out the data in the blob column was direct document (word or pdf) but was compressed.  So when querying the blob column used utl_compress to decompress and then directly utl_file output to a physical file.

select UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS(BLOB_COLUMN) into v_blob from TABLE where ID =

Thank you to all who responded.